# SQL Server query Debit Credit columns show only Debit values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to select the debit values only?

Example table:

```
 ID     Debit     Credit
----    ------    ------
  1     500.00      0.00
  2     500.00      0.00
  3       0.00    100.00
```

Select ID, Debit From table (This is not the result set that I want)

```
 ID     Debit     
----    ------    
 1      500.00
 2      500.00
 3        0.00
```

What I need is to have a result set that looks like this.

```
 ID     Debit     
----    ------    
 1      500.00
 2      500.00
```

Select ID, Debit from table Where (?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ID, Debit from table Where Debit <> 0
```

I don't know if negatives have a meaning... If not, then:

```
Select ID, Debit from table Where Debit > 0
```

And because you may have NULLs in this field:

```
Select ID, Debit from table Where Debit IS NOT NULL AND Debit <> 0
```

Or

```
Select ID, Debit from table Where Debit IS NOT NULL AND Debit > 0
```